# UITableView does not work after switching rootViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4, ios5

I couldn't find any tutorial that i could understand about switching views but i found out that i can switch them by changing the window's `rootViewController` property.

The problem is my other view has 2 `UITableView`s in it, but they don't respond to swipes when the controller just became the `rootViewController`, but after i turn my ipad 90 degrees the view changes to landscape then it starts to work.

Can anyone tell me how to make them work when the view is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change directly the `windows rootViewController property` and have it to work, because the system doesn't get notify that that change occurred. That is why the change took effect only when the system asked for that view again.
You need to use a method to change it.  Depending on your architecture you may want to use a method from [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController)

```
transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:
```

[UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

```
setViewControllers:animated:
```

[UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) :

```
transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
```

Comment: Actually, a better approach for a `UINavigationController` is using `pushViewController:animated:` and `popViewControllerAnimated:` (or `popToViewController:animated:` or `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`). But +1 for the "the system does not get notified of"

Comment: @FelipeSabino - I totally agree the `push` and `pop` are better to construct a view hierarchy with a UINavigationController, but from the question I had the impression that he wanted to change the root and not build a view hierarchy.

Comment: Hmmm, well observed. So, setting the controllers stack is definitely the way to go ;)

Comment: Actually i've started to write for ios a few days ago, and i usually fail to follow tutorials because of the ios4-ios5 differences. So i'm just trying to figure out how to change from a view to another view in best way possible.

Comment: @user1126446 there is on iTunesU very good tutorial that are Stanford classes given by Apple staff on iPhone / iPad development. The newest one covers iOS 5 features.